# To-Do List in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

New to Android programming and having trouble programming an app with activities for to-do list, time log, expenses log and exercise log. Each activity is a listview with multiple choice layout. For example:

TO-DO:
This is a single page to-do list. The user cannot add additional to-do list pages. Therefore, the screen appears blank with two buttons at the bottom: ADD and DELETE. The user will use the Android back button to exit this activity and return to the main View. You must provide a nice background for this to-do list that works well with the theme of this feature and is not too “noisy” to look at. You should use a List View that is scroll-able. Each to-do entry needs to provide a way for the user to mark it as completed.
The ADD button displays a popup text box for the user to enter their to-do item. The popup has a DONE and CANCEL button. Pressing DONE adds the to-do item at the end of the to-do list. Pressing CANCEL returns the user to the to-do list but does not add the text from the popup.

I need to use fragments but having trouble understanding how to program the ListFragment that would be attached to all activities.

TO-DO activity:

```
    public class ToDoActivity extends Activity implements ListViewFragment.OnItemSelectedListener {

    final Context context = this;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView toDoList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.todo);

        // SET ACTION BAR
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, arrayList);
    }


        @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonItemSelected(String link) {
        if (link.contentEquals("add")) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            dialog.setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_dialog, null));
            dialog.setTitle("Add Task");
            dialog.show();

            final EditText task = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etTaskInfo);
            Button btDone = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btDone);

            btDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    arrayList.add(task.getText().toString());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            Button btCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btCancel);

            btCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
        if (link.contentEquals("delete")) {
            int count = toDoList.getCount();
            SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = toDoList.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
                if (checkedItemPositions.get(i))
                    arrayList.remove(i);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.menuitem_exit) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
        }

        if (id == R.id.menuitem_help) {
            Intent helpIntent = new Intent(ToDoActivity.this, Help.class);
            helpIntent.putExtra("helptext", getString(R.string.help_todo));
            startActivity(helpIntent);
        }

        if (id == R.id.menuitem_settings) {
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(ToDoActivity.this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

LISTVIEWFRAGMENT:

```
 public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private String information;
    private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

        Button btAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btAdd);
        btAdd.setOnClickListener(actionSelectedListener);

        Button btDel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btDelete);
        btDel.setOnClickListener(actionSelectedListener);

        return view;
    }

    private OnClickListener actionSelectedListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String description = (String) getView().getContentDescription();
            information = description;
            passSelection();
        }
    };

    public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
        void onButtonItemSelected(String link);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
            listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
        }
        else {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "must implement ListViewFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    public void passSelection() {
        listener.onButtonItemSelected(information);
    }
}
```

LIST_FRAGMENT.XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/todo_bkgd"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:background="@color/light_grey"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btAdd"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:text="@string/add_btn"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btDelete"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:text="@string/delete_btn"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/delete_btn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

TODO.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!--FRAGMENT: list_fragment.xml-->
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            class="mcgill.christina.personaldataassistant_actionbar.ListViewFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/list_fragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your list Fragment has no adapter or listview. Start with that

Comment: Also, careful `ListFragment` is already a class in the Android library.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html

Comment: Thanks, I've added the adapter and listview. I'm confused now with having the array list within the fragment - how do I use this fragment in the to do activity?

Comment: Suggestions: read the well written Android tutorials on how you load and display a Fragment

Comment: I've updated my code, can you please see my new question?

Comment: Well, does it work? Your Fragment should be displayed even if you don't open a dialog... If that is not what you want, don't use the `<fragment` tag. Use the FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction method of loading a Fragment instead. Also, your Fragment need to be `view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);` instead of how you currently search for the ListView because that's the ID in your XML

Comment: Maybe try a different example...  https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments#dynamically

Answer (score 0):

The adapter in the Activity is entirely separate from the adapter within the Fragment. Matter of fact, the adapter in the Activity isn't set to anything, and the Fragment adapter is just empty, so that perfectly explains why you see nothing.

Basically, move your add and delete methods over to the Fragment class. I'm not sure how you want to handle the add and remove buttons, but you might be making the process more difficult than what you need. In other words, your Fragment is just a ListView... There's really no need for it

Anyways if you really want it, to test the Fragment even displays anything, add data to what you already have

For example

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

        // fixed this id reference 
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.add("Working?");

        return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've updated my code to make my fragment more useful. But clicking on add does not work, app crashes due to a null pointer exception. Looks like the ToDoActivity is not receiving the string link from the fragment.

Comment: I can't guess what the stacktrace says  for the NullPointerException says, but it should point you at the line number of the null value

Comment: Yes it points to "if (link.contentEquals("add"))". The problem is the link String.

Comment: Well, I don't what `getView().getContentDescription()` does, but I'm pretty sure that isn't how to get the text of a Button. You have to cast the clicked view to a Button object, then call getText